# Why can't I set a rotation keyframe on this object without it setting the same keyframe on the parent armature? Deleting one KF deletes the other too

Tags: animation, armature, bezier-curves, keyframes

Here's a partial hierarchy of my current Blender scene:

```
Armature
\--Mesh 1 (parented to a bone)
   \--Bezier 1
      \--Bezier 2
      \--Bezier 3
```

Bezier 2 and 3 were "Duplicate Linked" from Bezier 1, so they all share the same curve data, but I'm not sure whether that has anything to do with the issue.

Anyway, what happens is, I rotate Bezier 1, and then set a keyframe on that rotation. It appears to work fine at first. But then when I change frames, suddenly I see the entire armature rotate to some weird angle. Then, when I click on the armature, I see a keyframe on its (object-level) rotation as well, which I never set. I can remove the armature keyframe and put the rotation back to zero, but then it removes the keyframe from Bezier 1 as well.

I don't want to share the .blend file just yet, but I do have a copy saved at this point for when I do in the future. In the meantime though, is anyone aware of anything that could potentially cause this behavior? Or can it only be a bug in Blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a case of user error. Bezier 1 was using the same action as the armature, and this is the normal behavior in that situation.

I was (incorrectly) thinking that an action just stores the entire timeline, including keyframes for each individual object that uses that action, because I hadn't had any problems using it that way with armatures. But in actuality, an action just stores the individual properties that are animated, and applies them to every object that performs the action, unless the object doesn't have that property. Which does make more sense in hindsight. I haven't had any problems using a single action for multiple armatures, but that's only because they don't have any bone names in common.